# word search puzzle

Tags: iphone

Can anyone tell me how to create word search puzzle....

Any ideas where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea should eventually be an app that links to a database. Your app should get random words out of that database, and fill it in a table with multiple rows and heights. After a few words, let the app fill the remaining empty table cells with random letters. All this can be checked using arrays.
Last, program you app to check how the user slides or touches the screen, and let the app react accordingly. 
That should be the idea of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Probably do a lot of reading up on it first!

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/11/how-to-create-your-first-iphone-application/

Comment: I know about creating iphone app. But I am not able to get logic for word search puzzle like game..

Answer (score 0):

[there?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started)